# How to install apd in debian php5

Tags: installation, php5

I have a debian etch server running php+apache. I am using php5-cli, php5-common, php5-mysql and php5-sybase. I want to use [APD](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7213) to profile my php code, but a php5-apd package is not available in debian. Even pear package is missing (only php4-pear is available). I do not want to downgrade to php4 for fear of breaking some thing. What would be the safe way to install apd for php5 in Debian Etch?

with regards,

raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian don't always put the version number in the packages. Php Pear is just in as php-pear for version 5, the default version. [See here](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/php-pear)

Once that is installed, the pecl tool will become available.

```
pecl install apd
```

Will install the latest version of apd for you. If you do anything to your php.ini or include paths, these may need to be modified to pick up the install.

---

Answer (score 2):

APD is part of PECL. You can use the PECL installer to install the package:

```
pecl install apd
```

It will download, compile and install the package automatically. You may then need to enable it in php.ini.